# How to match 2 criteria in arrays?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

**I really need your help regarding this matter, please!**

I have got no error, everything is working smoothly....

All I need is that except for matching 1 to 1 column, I need to match 2 to 2 columns.

Column A in source sheet to column G in target sheet (already here) I want to add also to that Column B in source sheet to Column H in target sheet.

Summary: Match 2 col in source sheet (A & B) to 2 col in target sheet (G & H).

I hope you got my question? thanks!

**First Part of code: No Issue**

```
Sub Get_Data()

Const NUM_DATA_COLS As Long = 4

Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
Set SourceSheet = GetWorkbook(Source).Worksheets("Data")
Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim SourceLastRow As Long, TargetLastRow As Long
SourceLastRow = SourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
TargetLastRow = TargetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Primary_Fields(1 To NUM_DATA_COLS), Foreign_Fields(1 To NUM_DATA_COLS), n As Long
Dim i As Long, v, m

Dim rngPrimary_Key As Range 
Dim Foreign_Key As Variant
```

**Second Part of code:**

**How to add another (rngPrimary_Key2) and (Foreign_Key2) to match 2 columns to 2 columns**

I am only matching those
Set rngPrimary_Key = SourceSheet.Range("A2:A" & SourceLastRow)
Foreign_Key = TargetSheet.Range("G2:G" & TargetLastRow).Value

I need to add those to the matching criteria
Set rngPrimary_Key2 = SourceSheet.Range("B2:B" & SourceLastRow)
Foreign_Key2 = TargetSheet.Range("H2:H" & TargetLastRow).Value

^- if these two columns match in both sheets, then store in an array instead of only matching one column.

```
Set rngPrimary_Key = SourceSheet.Range("A2:A" & SourceLastRow)
Foreign_Key = TargetSheet.Range("G2:G" & TargetLastRow).Value

For n = 1 To NUM_DATA_COLS
    Primary_Fields(n) = SourceSheet.Range("B2:B" & SourceLastRow).Offset(0, n - 1).Value
    Foreign_Fields(n) = EmptyCopy(Foreign_Key) 'empty array for results
Next n

' get matching rows and copy values to arrays
For i = LBound(Foreign_Key, 1) To UBound(Foreign_Key, 1)
    v = Foreign_Key(i, 1)
    m = Application.Match(v, rngPrimary_Key, 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then            'check got a match
        For n = 1 To NUM_DATA_COLS
            Foreign_Fields(n)(i, 1) = Primary_Fields(n)(m, 1)
        Next n
    End If
Next i

' / Write (Keys-IndexMatch) in Range offset Foreign_Field_1 2
Place2DArray TargetSheet.Range("H2"), Foreign_Fields(1)
Place2DArray TargetSheet.Range("i2"), Foreign_Fields(2)
Place2DArray TargetSheet.Range("J2"), Foreign_Fields(3)
Place2DArray TargetSheet.Range("K2"), Foreign_Fields(4)

End Sub
```

**Rest of the code, not related to my question**

```
'return an empty array of same dimensions as 'arr'

 Function EmptyCopy(arr)
Dim rv
ReDim rv(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2))
EmptyCopy = rv
End Function

'copy a 1-based 2-d array 'arr' to a worksheet, starting at cell 'c'
Sub Place2DArray(c As Range, arr)
c.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Zatary could you please [edit] your post & disclose the what error/prolem you are finding so far will help us to fix the code !!

Comment: @RajeshS Edited, It's working fine I just need to know how match 2 columns to 2 columns instead of matching just 1 column to 1 column, that's all. thanks!

Comment: since you are tying to pull records may e multiple records using two Criteria then better use an array formula like this,,, `m = Application.Evaluate("INDEX,,,`       OR  
 `Range("A1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($F$2:$F$25,MATCH(1,(B1=$C$2:$C$25)*(B2=$B$2:$B$25),0))"` ,,,here  B1 & B2 are cells contains criteria.

Comment: @RajeshS thank you for the comment, would you please help me with merging this to the syntax? Where to put column a to match with b and (put column g to match with h) in this formula?

Comment: In your second part of the code I'm finding that you have used m= Application. MATCH ,, here only you need to use the ARRAY formula !  Like `m=Application.Evaluate("=INDEX($A$2:A,MATCH(1,(B1=$B2:B)*(B2=$G$2:G),0))"`

Comment: @RajeshS It returns Compile Error, Expected: list separator or) BTW i need to match (A with G) and (B with H) not (A with B) and (A with G) thanks for your help, any suggestions?

Comment: ,,you need to adjust cell references if & when required,, and the suggested command is the correct syntax,, I'v used it,,!